# jQuery scrollIntent, similar to hoverIntent

Tags: jquery, scroll, hoverintent

I am looking for a function similar to hoverIntent, but for scrolling. I have a function that moves the sidebar to stay put while scrolling. They thing is, the moving/calculations take place really close together, causing the "always visible" box to flicker while scrolling. I am looking an invent that fires only when it is very likely that the user is trying to scroll to that position. Then, I will do some fancy easing effect rather than a simply css property change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris Coyier has a great tutorial/freebie on how to do this over at CSS Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

You can see a [demo of his approach](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ScrollingSidebar/).